# how can I open a .npy file and work on it by networkx?

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I'm working on a project and I want to work with networkx package.
The file that has the adjacency matrix of the graph is of .npy format. So first I want to load it by numpy and then I want to do some graph functions on it by networkx.

I wrote this code to get info about my graph but this is wrong. I searched for networkx functions but I'm confused witch function can I use for a .npy file?

anybody can help me to get the info of the graph that I loaded by numpy??

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

total = np.load('totaldata.npy')
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(total)
print (nx.info(G))
```

when I run the code I get this error:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/convert_matrix.py",
line 550, in from_numpy_matrix
n, m = A.shape

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: The code you posted looks like it should work. Could you clarify what doesn't work?

Comment: @JoshKarpel I added the error that I get to the end of my question.

Comment: It looks like the shape of your data isn't what you expect it to be. Could you print out `total.shape`? Do you control the creation of the `.npy` file (i.e., can you post the code that makes it)? You may need to do an `np.reshape` [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

Comment: @JoshKarpel yes thank you. that was my fault! The shape of the data was different from what I expected.